# Rails 6 application not deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a simple Rails 6 application (API only) which works fine in development, but when deploying to Heroku I get this error:

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Compiling…
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        error Command "webpack" not found.
remote:
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
```

What do I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Right, according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933431/failed-deploying-rails-app-with-webpacker-to-heroku) I had to do this and it worked:

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

Comment: I had a Rails 5 app but the exact same problem. I already had both `nodejs` and `ruby` buildpacks set up, but I guess the *ordering* of the buildpacks matter. Who knew?! Running this command fixed the problem for me and allowed me to deploy.